# How to identify performance issue query - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to build a query to retrieve data from 3 different tables that join to a lookup table.

My issue is that the query takes a long time to run (took 1 hour and I gave up waiting assuming something was wrong, a python script is running the query and writing the result in a file)

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.product_id SEPARATOR ':') AS b_pids,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.product_id SEPARATOR ':') AS c_pids,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.product_id SEPARATOR ':') AS d_ids
FROM a_table a
LEFT JOIN b_table b ON a.customer_account_guid = b.customer_account_guid 
LEFT JOIN c_table c ON b.customer_account_guid = c.customer_account_guid 
LEFT JOIN d_table d ON c.customer_account_guid = d.customer_account_guid 
WHERE a.category = 'product_category' AND a.location = 'UK' GROUP BY a.id
```

The explain result for this query is:

```
id  | select_type | table  | type       | possible_keys                                                                            |   key                     | key_len | ref                     | rows    |filtered |Extra
1   | SIMPLE      | a      | ref        | PRIMARY,idx_id,idx_customer_account_guid,idx_category_location,idx_category,idx_location | idx_category_location     | 47      | const,const             | 1211986 |100      |Using index condition
1   | SIMPLE      | b      | ref        | idx_customer_account_guid                                                                | idx_customer_account_guid | 300     | a.customer_account_guid | 6       |100      |NULL
1   | SIMPLE      | c      | ref        | idx_customer_account_guid                                                                | idx_customer_account_guid | 300     | b.customer_account_guid | 18      |100      |NULL
1   | SIMPLE      | d      | ref        | idx_customer_account_guid                                                                | idx_customer_account_guid | 300     | c.customer_account_guid | 2       |100      |NULL
```

The table records (count) are:

a_table - `3 million`

b_table - `8 million`

c_table - `2 million`

d_table - `4 million`

As you can see indexes seem to be alright and query isn't super complicated, any ideas why it takes more than 1 hour? I assume it shouldn't take that long with the counts above, or am I wrong?

Comment: How many rows do you actually get in the result? Also, 300 seems to be a bit high for a GUID length. It might help if you reduce the index length (or the field length) to the actual max GUID length.

Comment: should be around 1million results... thanks for the suggestions, I will reduce the index len and see if it helps!

Comment: can you destinguish the time taken to ***run the SQL query***,and the time taken *for python to write the results to the file*. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating ridiculous numbers of rows with the joins.  Instead, aggregate *before* joining:

```
SELECT a.id, b.b_pids, c.c_pids, d.d_ids
FROM a_table a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.customer_account_guid, GROUP_CONCAT(b.product_id SEPARATOR ':') as b_pids
      FROM b_table b
      GROUP BY b.customer_account_guid
     ) b
     ON a.customer_account_guid = b.customer_account_guid LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.customer_account_guid, GROUP_CONCAT(c.product_id SEPARATOR ':') as c_pids
      FROM c_table c
      GROUP BY b.customer_account_guid
     ) c
     ON a.customer_account_guid = c.customer_account_guid LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT d.customer_account_guid, GROUP_CONCAT(d.product_id SEPARATOR ':') as d_pids
      FROM d_table d
      GROUP BY d.customer_account_guid
     ) d
     ON a.customer_account_guid = d.customer_account_guid 
WHERE a.category = 'product_category' AND a.location = 'UK';
```

I removed the `DISTINCT` from the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  You might still need that.

EDIT:

Given your filtering in the outer query, correlated subqueries might be the best approach:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.product_id SEPARATOR ':') as b_pids
        FROM b_table b
        WHERE a.customer_account_guid = b.customer_account_guid
       ) b_pids,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.product_id SEPARATOR ':') as b_pids
        FROM c_table c
        WHERE a.customer_account_guid = c.customer_account_guid
       ) b_pids,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d.product_id SEPARATOR ':') 
        FROM d_table d
        WHERE a.customer_account_guid = d.customer_account_guid
       ) d_pids
FROM a_table a LEFT JOIN
WHERE a.category = 'product_category' AND a.location = 'UK';
```

For this version, you want indexes on `a_table(category, location, customer_account_guid)` and for each of the other tables, `(customer_account_guid, product_id)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I tried it although it seemed to make it more complex based on the result of explain. And when running it, with limit 100, it takes 15minutes to execute... not sure why

Comment: I was heading to the direction of your edit solution, but wasn't sure the best way to do it... the edit suggestion did the trick, it ran in less than 10! ty so much

Comment: I am curious why this solution out performes the left joins, if you have some spare time could you help me understand?